# How does Spring Data (MongoDB) read an object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am currently working on a project using the Spring framework and SpringData MongoDB (v.1.6.1 RELEASE). I now want to add a property to a stored object, that would simplify its retrieval, but I need to compute this property based on the state of the object at the point of time I want to save it. I tried to put that computation within the getter method of the object, but somehow SpringData is not using the getter to access the property.

**The concrete example is the following:**
I am storing events in the database and the events are allowed to span over several dates, creating a multi-date event. The events are defined by a start date (LocalDateTime) and an end date (LocalDateTime). I now want to store the information, if the event is a multi-date event or not, within the database. Concluding I added a boolean variable to the event (multiDate). Within the getter (isMultiDate) I am comparing the start and end date and returning true or false (depending on the dates).

My event object:

```
public class Event
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String location;
    private double locationLat;
    private double locationLog;

    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private int startDateDayOfMonth, startDateMonth, startDateYear, startDateHour, startDateMinute;
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private int endDateDayOfMonth, endDateMonth,endDateYear, endDateHour, endDateMinute;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastChanged;

    @Transient
    private LocalDateTime startDateTime;

    @Transient
    private LocalDateTime endDateTime;

    private boolean multiDate;

    @DBRef
    @NotEmpty
    private List<Division> invitedDivision;

    public Event() {}

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public double getLocationLat()
    {
        return locationLat;
    }

    public void setLocationLat(double locationLat)
    {
        this.locationLat = locationLat;
    }

    public double getLocationLog()
    {
        return locationLog;
    }

    public void setLocationLog(double locationLog)
    {
        this.locationLog = locationLog;
    }

    public int getStartDateDayOfMonth()
    {
        return startDateDayOfMonth;
    }

    public void setStartDateDayOfMonth(int startDateDayOfMonth)
    {
        this.startDateDayOfMonth = startDateDayOfMonth;
    }

    public int getStartDateMonth()
    {
        return startDateMonth;
    }

    public void setStartDateMonth(int startDateMonth)
    {
        this.startDateMonth = startDateMonth;
    }

    public int getStartDateYear()
    {
        return startDateYear;
    }

    public void setStartDateYear(int startDateYear)
    {
        this.startDateYear = startDateYear;
    }

    public int getStartDateHour()
    {
        return startDateHour;
    }

    public void setStartDateHour(int startDateHour)
    {
        this.startDateHour = startDateHour;
    }

    public int getStartDateMinute()
    {
        return startDateMinute;
    }

    public void setStartDateMinute(int startDateMinute)
    {
        this.startDateMinute = startDateMinute;
    }

    public int getEndDateDayOfMonth()
    {
        return endDateDayOfMonth;
    }

    public void setEndDateDayOfMonth(int endDateDayOfMonth)
    {
        this.endDateDayOfMonth = endDateDayOfMonth;
    }

    public int getEndDateMonth()
    {
        return endDateMonth;
    }

    public void setEndDateMonth(int endDateMonth)
    {
        this.endDateMonth = endDateMonth;
    }

    public int getEndDateYear()
    {
        return endDateYear;
    }

    public void setEndDateYear(int endDateYear)
    {
        this.endDateYear = endDateYear;
    }

    public int getEndDateHour()
    {
        return endDateHour;
    }

    public void setEndDateHour(int endDateHour)
    {
        this.endDateHour = endDateHour;
    }

    public int getEndDateMinute()
    {
        return endDateMinute;
    }

    public void setEndDateMinute(int endDateMinute)
    {
        this.endDateMinute = endDateMinute;
    }

    public Date getLastChanged()
    {
        return lastChanged;
    }

    public void setLastChanged(Date lastChanged)
    {
        this.lastChanged = lastChanged;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStartDateTime()
    {
        startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(startDateYear, startDateMonth, startDateDayOfMonth, startDateHour, startDateMinute);
        return startDateTime;
    }

    public void setStartDateTime(LocalDateTime startDateTime)
    {
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
        if(startDateTime != null)
        {
            startDateYear = startDateTime.getYear();
            startDateMonth = startDateTime.getMonthValue();
            startDateDayOfMonth = startDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
            startDateHour = startDateTime.getHour();
            startDateMinute = startDateTime.getMinute();
        }
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEndDateTime()
    {
        endDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(endDateYear, endDateMonth, endDateDayOfMonth, endDateHour, endDateMinute);
        return endDateTime;
    }

    public void setEndDateTime(LocalDateTime endDateTime)
    {
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
        if(endDateTime != null)
        {
            endDateYear = endDateTime.getYear();
            endDateMonth = endDateTime.getMonthValue();
            endDateDayOfMonth = endDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
            endDateHour = endDateTime.getHour();
            endDateMinute = endDateTime.getMinute();
        }
    }

    public List<Division> getInvitedDivision()
    {
        return invitedDivision;
    }

    /**
     * The function is setting all invited divisions, but is optimizing the set by eliminating unnecessary divisions.
     * @param invitedDivision
     */
    public void setInvitedDivision(List<Division> invitedDivision)
    {
        if(invitedDivision != null)
        {
            this.invitedDivision = DivisionManagementController.getOptimizedSetOfDivisions(invitedDivision);
        } else
        {
            this.invitedDivision = invitedDivision;
        }
    }

    public void addDivision(Division division)
    {
        if(invitedDivision == null)
        {
            invitedDivision = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        invitedDivision.add(division);
    }

    public boolean isMultiDate()
    {
        return (startDateDayOfMonth != endDateDayOfMonth) || (startDateMonth != endDateMonth) || (startDateYear != endDateYear);
    }

    public void setMultiDate(boolean multiDate)
    {
        this.multiDate = multiDate;
    }
}
```

What am I getting wrong? Why is SpringData not using the public getter to access a private variable? (I actually returned always true and the database still only showed storing false).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I am still not clear about the issue, but try this

```
public boolean isMultiDate()
{
    multiDate = (startDateDayOfMonth != endDateDayOfMonth) || (startDateMonth != endDateMonth) || (startDateYear != endDateYear);
    return multiDate;
}
```

Comment: Maybe ask for clarification in a comment before answering.

Comment: agreed.  @Fat_FS, would you clarify if it is an issue with multiDate is not being updated or the isMultiDate() method is not being called.  But to update the value in MongodB, use the method I suggested but call db.save() right after.  You may want to change the method name to getMultiDate() to make sure the method is being called.

Comment: The problem is that isMultiDate() is somehow never called. 

Use-case: I create the object, entering all information like start and end date, but I am not actively calling the isMultiDate() function (i could do that I know). That means the multiDate value is NOT set. When calling db.save() I hoped Spring Data would access multiDate by calling isMultiDate() to read the value and afterwards store it within the DB, but somehow this is NOT the case.

Comment: @Fat_FS, thanks for the clarification.  Calling db.save() will not make mongodb to call isMultiDate().  I would recommend that every time you add a valid end date, you set the multidate flag to true then call db.save().  That will save the value correctly into the database.